# UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, applications

My wife and I are applying for UK visas. How should I answer the questions about money?

1. Must all the questions about my money that are required to be in GBP be answered in GBP?
2. I have stated in my application that we are traveling together. How do I answer about her expenses in the UK (how much the trip will cost her)? Should I reduce my own expenses by half and show just her costs?

Answer (score 0):

Cost of Hotel for 2 £35-£50 per night (Not central London)
Transport per day £10-20 for 2 people.
Eating out £15-£25 for 2 people.
Entertainment £10-£20 per day for 2.

etc...

Comment: Can you please edit this answer so it explains why you give these numbers? As it is now, it runs a big risk of being deleted as not an answer to the question asked.